# Posicionamento de um botão

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Estou com dificuldade em fazer o posicionamento de um botão responsivo, sempre que consigo colocar o posicionamento correto num ecrã com uma certa resolução sempre que vejo no outro ecrã volta a ficar mal.

Este é o meu layout:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O botão que eu mencionei é o que tem o icon "+".

O meu código até agora:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <div class=" col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 mrg">
        <div class="row padInternalRow">
            <div class="col-4 border rounded p-0">
                <img class="float-left imagem" height="100%" width="100%" src="imagens\user.png" alt="Card image cap">
            </div>
            <div class="col-7 border pr-auto rounded">
                <div class="row h-50 flex-column pl-1">
                    <h5 class="text-left mb-0">Nome:</h5>
                       <p class="text-left">Nome exemplo</p>
                </div>
                <div class="row px-0 h-50 mt-1">
                    <div class="col-10 pl-1 mx-0">
                        <h5 class="text-left mb-0">Função:</h5>
                        <p class="text-left">Função exemplo</p>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-1 ml-auto mt-auto">
                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-light p-0 btn-circle" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewCandModal">
                             <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
                         </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Sua pergunta não ficou clara... Ele tem que ficar alinhado sempre na mesma posição? Se sim qual seria a posição? Onde vc quer que ele fique? Não deu para entender qual é o problema de alinhamento entre um ecrã e outro.

Comment: Peço desculpa por não deixar a pergunta clara Hugo, o objetivo é que o botão ficasse localizado no canto inferior direito mas não encostado com as borders, obrigado na mesma :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simples assim ^^

```css
.btn_over{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-10px;
  right:-10px
}
.btn_over2{
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  left:100%;
  transform: translate(-100%, -100%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <div class=" col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 mrg">
        <div class="row padInternalRow">
            <div class="col-4 border rounded p-0">
                <img class="float-left imagem" height="100%" width="100%" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Card image cap">
            </div>
            <div class="col-7 border pr-auto rounded">
                <div class="row h-50 flex-column pl-1">
                    <h5 class="text-left mb-0">Nome:</h5>
                       <p class="text-left">Nome exemplo</p>
                </div>
                <div class="row px-0 h-50 mt-1">
                    <div class="col-10 pl-1 mx-0">
                        <h5 class="text-left mb-0">Função:</h5>
                        <p class="text-left">Função exemplo</p>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-1 ml-auto mt-auto">
                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-light p-0 btn-circle btn_over" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewCandModal">
                             <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
                         </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class=" col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 mrg">
        <div class="row padInternalRow">
            <div class="col-4 border rounded p-0">
                <img class="float-left imagem" height="100%" width="100%" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Card image cap">
            </div>
            <div class="col-7 border pr-auto rounded">
                <div class="row h-50 flex-column pl-1">
                    <h5 class="text-left mb-0">Nome:</h5>
                       <p class="text-left">Nome exemplo</p>
                </div>
                <div class="row px-0 h-50 mt-1">
                    <div class="col-10 pl-1 mx-0">
                        <h5 class="text-left mb-0">Função:</h5>
                        <p class="text-left">Função exemplo</p>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-1 ml-auto mt-auto">
                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-light p-0 btn-circle btn_over2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewCandModal">
                             <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
                         </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Obrigado, a sua forma resultou mas não pode ter os valores negativos no código do css nos parametros "bottom" e "right", muito obrigado na mesma :)

Comment: vou faze rum update com outra opção